# F#: namespaces / modules are out of reach

Tags: visual-studio-2012, f#, type-providers

I just started with F#. I am with MS VS 2012.

I am trying to follow some MSDN examples (f.ex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh225374(v=vs.110).aspx) and I have already hit a snag: namespaces that should in theory be accessible are in fact out of reach.

```
open System.Data
```

results in "The namespace 'Data' is not defined.

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
```

generates in "The namespace 'TypeProviders' is not defined.

Not sure what I should do. 
Do the packages need to be installed somewhere? The MSDN tutorial does not mention this.

Thanks.

Comment: As explained below that's exactly the error you'll get if you try to reference a namespace in an assembly that is not present in your project.  This is nothing specific to F#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the project and select 'Add reference…', then under 'Assemblies', select 'Extensions'. Then you should find `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders` in the assembly list.

Alternatively, you can install the `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders` [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/0.0.1):